# PHPMailer bounce email address shows in sender mailbox

Tags: phpmailer

I am using a PHP script to send emails using PHPMailer (on an ovh web server).

- With the following script :

```
      $mail->isMail();
      ......
      $mail->addReplyTo('postmaster@mydomain.fr', 'Site');
      $mail->SetFrom('postmaster@mydomain.fr', 'Site');
```

Emails get delivered to my gmail account BUT not to other addresses (e.g. my Business email).

- With the following script :

```
      $mail->isMail();
      ......
      $mail->addReplyTo('postmaster@mydomain.fr', 'Site');
      $mail->Sender = 'postmaster@mydomain.fr';
```

Emails get delivered to other addresses (e.g. my Business email) BUT not to gmail.

Also the sender appears as
`bounce-id=D004=U58180. …… .net`

which is not so friendly.

Is there a way to solve those issues ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `setFrom` by itself will result in `Sender` being set to the same value as your from address (look at the code in the `setFrom` method). So in your second example you're setting the envelope sender, but not the from address, which is likely not what you want.

You may find it easier to use SMTP to localhost instead of `isMail()`; just changing that method to `isSMTP()` should be enough to do that. That way you  can set `SMTPDebug = 2` and see exactly what your local mail server is saying.

Separately, you don't need to set a reply-to address if it's the same as your from address – PHPMailer will simply ignore it if you try to set them to the same value anyway.

Comment: Thanks. But If I add a `SetFrom` it does not work (for my business email). I tried to just have  `$mail->SetFrom('postmaster@muydomain.fr', 'Site', TRUE);` with no success either. BTW, I tried to use `isSMTP()` but I had weird quota warnings from my provider.

Comment: My guess : when using isMail() I can put any mail address (fake or not) in the `SetFrom` and it will work for Gmail. Somehow my business email needs to know the true sender (which I do not know when using ovh).

Comment: Gmail does do DMARC checks, so I would expect forged from addresses to fail there too. When using `mail()` any SMTP problems will not be reported back to PHP, but will be in your local mail server's log, usually somewhere like `/var/log/mail.log`